# How would I write this as another form of PHP

Tags: php

Hey I had a question I can not figure out how to write this code:

```
<div><?=$rs['username']." ~ ".$rs["webcam_status"]?></div>
```

When I have my code already set up as only 1 php markup, the code:

```
<?php
echo"
<!-- header -->
";
    include "../../access/$template/header.php";
    echo "

<!-- content -->

<div><?=$rs['username']." ~ ".$rs["webcam_status"]?></div>

<!-- content -->

<!--footer-->
";
    include "../../access/$template/footer.php";
    echo "

";
?>
```

I know how to write it differently, does anybody know how to write it that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't cause PHP to output PHP and then parse that PHP and execute it.

Add your data via string concatenation instead.

Better yet: Geek `echo` statements to a minimum, and drop out of PHP mode with `<?` when you are just outputting static data.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo"
<!-- header -->
";
    include "../../access/$template/header.php";
    echo "

<!-- content -->

<div>".$rs['username']." ~ ".$rs["webcam_status"]."</div>

<!-- content -->

<!--footer-->
";
    include "../../access/$template/footer.php";
    echo "

";
?>
```